# Why does Google Talk say I'm logged in, while I show up as not logged in on the Google Talk phone app?

Tags: google-talk

I can clearly see myself as logged in on Google Talk, on the version that comes up on the computer.

When I see myself on the Google Talk app, which I though was the same thing, it comes up that I am offline. I thought they should correspond. Is this not true?

Answer (score 1):

No.They are two different things. One is for phone notifications, etc, and the other is for IM'ing, basically. Just go online in GTalk, though if you can't, I'm sorry to say I don't know why.